# Google signin with signInWithRedirect always takes me back to the login page

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm having a hard time getting the Firebase `signInWithRedirect` with google to work. Below is the doc I've been looking at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin.

I have a login page which contains a button. When the button is clicked it take you to google sign in page. However every time I sign in with google it redirects me back to the login page of my app. Part of the code is shown below:

```
login() {
      const auth = getAuth();

      signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
      console.log("AAA")
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        console.log("BBB")
        if (user) {
          this.$router.push('home')
        } else {
          getRedirectResult(auth)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("WIN0")
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            const token = credential.accessToken;

            // The signed-in user info.
            const user = result.user;
            console.log(token)
            console.log(user)
            console.log("WIN")
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("ERROR0")
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            const email = error.customData.email;
            // The AuthCredential type that was used.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            console.log(errorCode)
            console.log(errorMessage)
            console.log(email)
            console.log(credential)
            console.log("ERROR")
            // ...
          });
        }
      })
```

From the console, I only ever see the log `AAA`, but I don't see any other logs at all. What am I missing? Thank you.

I should also mention that I'm doing this in vue js but I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I have `onAuthStateChanged` within the `login` function. Since the `SignInWithRedirect` takes to a different page and then redirects back to the page where it was called, in vue I basically moved the `onAuthStateChanged` to the `mounted` lifecycle hook.

```
mounted() {
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        console.log("BBB")
        if (user) {
          this.$router.push('home')
        } else {
          getRedirectResult(auth)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("WIN0")
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access Google APIs.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            const token = credential.accessToken;

            // The signed-in user info.
            const user = result.user;
            console.log(token)
            console.log(user)
            console.log("WIN")
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("ERROR0")
            // Handle Errors here.
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            const email = error.customData.email;
            // The AuthCredential type that was used.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
            console.log(errorCode)
            console.log(errorMessage)
            console.log(email)
            console.log(credential)
            console.log("ERROR")
            // ...
          });
        }
      })
}
```